# Find the value of the indefinite integral $~\int 1/{(x+\sin x)} \,dx~$

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals

It is easy to derive the indefinite integral $$I_1=\int\dfrac{1}{1+\sin x}\,dx~~~~~~~\text{or,}~~~~~~~~~I_2=\int\dfrac{x}{1+\sin x} \, dx$$which are respectively $$I_1=\tan x-\sec x+c_1~~~~~~~\text{and}~~~~~~~~~I_2=x(\tan x-\sec x) + \ln\left|\frac{\sec x+\tan x}{\sec x}\right|+c_2~,$$ where $~c_1,~c_2~$ are independent arbitrary constants. But now

> what is the value of the integral $$I_3=\int\dfrac{1}{x+\sin x} \, dx~~ ?$$

**N.B.** I was trying to solve the problem by using so many methods, but failed to do. Also trying by using online integral calculator. So I need your help. 
Sorry to say, please answer the problem (if you have it) rather to make the question closed. I have nothing to provide as additional information.

Comment: Why do you expect this integral to be elementary?

Comment: I don't think, it's an elementary integral but I just want its solution with proper justification.

Comment: What do you mean by *solution.* You say that you used an integrating engine. What did you get from there, for example?

Comment: I have no subscription of that integration engine. I use the free version available in the internet. But I get no solution.

Comment: OK, so you are saying that you don't think the solution can be expressed in closed form using only the elementary functions?

Comment: By solution, I mean the value of the integration. I have no idea if there be any closed form . If it has then someone please provide it to me.

Comment: It is not a definite integral, so you have to define what you mean by *value* since it will be a function, and not just some number.

Comment: As per my knowledge, by "the value of an indefinite integral" directly means a function with an integrating constant.

Comment: I don't think you're getting what I mean. For large values of $x,$ for example, the integrand can be expanded in the series $$\frac{1}{x}\sum_k (-1)^k\left(\frac{\sin x}{x}\right)^k,$$ most of whose terms have no elementary integral.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/119759/discussion-between-nmasanta-and-allawonder).